# more pong, more problems: collision mysteries of a novice game maker

Tags: canvas, functional-programming, collision-detection, velocity, pong

I'm making pong from scratch and I'm stuck with wired collision problems, and I don't know if it's because I'm flirting with functional style creating the game, or am I missing something. One: if the ball collides with a corner of on of the paddles, it bounces off double normal speed. also, I can't get the game to recognize the edges of the canvas, which is wired, because the tracker I put in to figure out the problems does recognize the edge, if you could help me out the jungle, I'd appreciate it. thanks.

http://codepen.io/JermaineBerkley/pen/yYZKPW

```
var c = document.getElementById('canvas');
c.width = window.innerWidth;
c.height = window.innerHeight; 
var context = c.getContext('2d');

var defaultSpeed = 5;

var nill = 0;
var cCurve = 2 * Math.PI;
var cRadius = 20;
var cx = 1;
var cy = 100;
var cVelX = defaultSpeed;
var cVelY = 2;

var rWidth = canvas.width / 30;
var rHeight = canvas.height / 3;
var rx = canvas.width - rWidth;
var ry = canvas.height / 2;
var rVelX = 0;
var rVelY = defaultSpeed;

var pWidth = canvas.width / 30;
var pHeight = canvas.height / 3;
var px = 0;
var py = canvas.height / 2;
var pVelX = 0;

var dHeight;
var dWidth;
var dColor;
var dXpos;
var dYpos;

// arguments for drawing and measurements
var x = function(num){ return num; };
var y = function(num){ return num; };
var radius = function(num){ return num; };
var startPoint = function(num){ return num; };
var endPoint = function(num){ return num; };
var width = function(num){ return num; };
var height = function(num){ return num; };

function collision(){
    // if the hits euther paddle, reverse the ball's y-velocity (horizonal direction))
    if(cx + cRadius >= rx && cy >= ry && cy <= ry + rHeight + 1 && cx + cRadius <= canvas.width){ cVelX -= 5; } 
    else if (cx - cRadius <= px + pWidth && cy >= py && cy <= py + pHeight + 1 && cx + cRadius >= 0) { cVelX += 5; }
    // also, if the ball collides with the top or the bottom of the canvas
    else if(cy <= 0){ 
        console.log('top'); 
        cVelY += 5; }
    else if(cy + cRadius > canvas.height && cx > px && cx + cRadius < rx){ 
        console.log('bottom'); 
        cVelY -= 5;
    }
    else if(cx < 0){  alert('point!'); }
    else if(cx > canvas.width){ alert('point!'); }
}

function AI(){
    if(cx >= canvas.width / 2){ 
        if(cy < (ry + rHeight) / 2 && ry >= 0){ 
            ry -= rVelY;
        }
    else if(cy > ry + rHeight / 2 && ry + rHeight <= canvas.height){ 
      ry += rVelY;
    }
  }
}

// drawing functions
function drawRect(x, y, width, height){
  // drawing the rect object (both player and computer)
  context.strokeStyle = 'black';
  context.rect(x, y, width, height);
  context.stroke();
}

function drawCircle(x, y, radius, startPoint, endPoint){
    // drawing the circle
    context.fillStyle = 'yellow';
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(x, y, radius, startPoint, endPoint);
    context.stroke();
}

window.addEventListener('keydown', keyHandler, false);

function keyHandler(event){
  //console.log(event.keyCode);
  if(event.keyCode === 38){ py -= defaultSpeed; if(py <= 0){ py = 0;  } }
  else if(event.keyCode === 40){ py += defaultSpeed; if(py + pHeight >= canvas.height){ py = canvas.height - pHeight;  } }
}

function pos(x, y) {
    document.getElementById('pos').innerHTML = 'The circle\'s X position is ' + x + ' and the circle\'s Y position is ' + y + '.' + ' The canvas\'s width is ' + canvas.width;
    if(x < 0 || x > canvas.width){
        document.getElementById('pos').innerHTML += ' edge reached!';
    }
}

function update(){

    c.width = window.innerWidth;
    c.height = window.innerHeight;

    // initializing the ball's x and y movement
    cx += cVelX; 
    cy += cVelY;
    console.log(px + pWidth);

    pos(cx, cy);
    drawCircle(x(cx), y(cy), radius(cRadius), startPoint(nill), endPoint(cCurve));
    drawRect(x(canvas.width / 2),y(nill),width(canvas.width / 60),height(canvas.height));
    drawRect(x(px),y(py),width(pWidth),height(pHeight));
    drawRect(x(rx),y(ry),width(rWidth),height(rHeight));
}

    function roll(){
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        // loop:
        //      AI
        //      collision
        //      update position
        AI();
        collision();
        update();
        window.requestAnimationFrame(roll);
    }
    window.requestAnimationFrame(roll);
```

Comment: There's no "functional style" in that code unless the term has lost all meaning over the last few years. What's the purpose of assigning the identity function to seven different variables?

Comment: one number, one function to handle it all.

Answer (score 0):

Easy fix, a simple error on the bouncing of the ball.

So let's follow the code.

- Ball moving left to right. `cVecX === 5` so add that to the ball position.
- Test determines that ball hits right paddle.
- The ball has not only hit the paddle but could be partly embedded in
  it.
- You subtract 5 units of speed from the ball. 'cVecX` is now equal to 0
- This stops/ or almost stops the ball for a whole frame, while still
  embedded in the paddle.
- Wait for the game to loop once more.
- The ball is not moved as the velocity is zero, but still touching the paddle  so you subtract 5 once more from `cVelX` it now = -5.

As you can see the ball has stop for a whole frame (game loop). 
It gets all messy because the velocity may have been greater than 5, in which case the ball would have spent 3 frames touching the paddle.

In the game world balls bounce with perfection. No energy is lost, the bounce happens for a very small amount of time. In reality balls do not enter solid objects.

So to reflect (bounce) something you simply negate the velocity value. `cVelX = -cVelX;` all the speed has been reflected in the opposite direction.

To fix the ball merging with the walls and paddles. On frame `n` the ball was outside the paddle. On frame n+1 the ball is partly inside the paddle. At some point between the two frames the ball collided and thus has been moving away from the paddle for some of the previous frame.

We can calculate when the ball hit and how far it has moved away from the paddle. The depth the ball is inside the paddle can give us how long ago the ball first touched the paddle during the time between the two frames. The ball has been moving in the opposite direction since then.

Thus move the ball away from the wall by the same amount it has entered the wall. `ball.pos.x -= (ball.pos.x - paddle.outsideEdge) * 2;` Will move the ball out and  away.

You get the picture. Leaving little details like that out can cause strange behaviour. You should alway be very careful with complex interactions.

I added a new variable in the sample. `ballInPlay` "because the alerts were bothering me. It stops the ball from doing collision tests after a point is scored. You should also remove the ball from game calculation when its not inplay.

Below is the fix for collision test.
I slashed it good and proper. Too many unneeded conditions.

```
var ballInPlay = true; // if ball is in play

function collision() {

    if(!ballInplay){
        // ball not in play so do nothing
        return;
    }
    // test right paddle
    if (cx + cRadius >= rx){  // is it at the right side; 
          if(cy >= ry  && cy <= ry + rHeight + 1){ // is it at the paddle
               cVelX = -cVelX;  // 100% reflection. Dont use cVelX -= 5;
               cx -= ((cx + cRadius) -rx)*2;  // ball needs to be moved away from 
                                          // the paddle by the amount it overlaps
          }
    }
    // test left paddle
    if (cx - cRadius <= px + pWidth ){ is in the paddle zone 
          if(cy >= py &&  cy <= py + pHeight + 1 )               // did it hit the paddle
              cVelX = -cVelX; // reflect 
              cx += ((px+pWidth)-(cx-cRadius))*2;  // and fix by amount it entered paddle
          }
    }
    // test top wall
    if (cy-cRadius <= 0) {
        cVelY = -cVelY;  // reflect and fix 
        cy += (cy-cRadius)*2; 
    }else
    //test bottom wall
    if (cy + cRadius > canvas.height)
        cVelY = -cVelY;  // reflect and fix 
        cy -= ((cy+cRadius)-canvas.height)*2;  // and fix by move  away from the wall
    }
    if (cx < 0) {
        // argh I hate alerts.
        // display a message on the canvas rather than blocking the page with an aller
        ballInplay = false; // a point scored so the ball is out of play
    } else 
    if (cx > canvas.width) {
        ballInPlay = false;
        // point to the AI
    }
}
```

Comment: I must admit, some of it is over my head, but damn good explanation of things. My fear is that I'll just copy it before I get the whole thing, but excellent explanation.

Comment: Thanks, I just had a read of it again, blimey I must have been blind that night as the are so many typos. Better fix them up. Well hope you get your game working how you want. Good luck.